# How to get server response status for posts in google analytics api or filtering out pages with 404 status?

Tags: php, wordpress, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have developed an custom google analytic plugin for wordpress for my own use.

I am able to retrieve `pagePathLevel1` of posts and views in result table, but it contains a lot of 404.html pages and some other pages having different `pagePathLevel1` but will get **server response code 404** if visited as those pages are not in my site now( some are already deleted and some links do not belongs to me )

I want to know page status of all the pages/posts for which I am able to retrieving the views and pagePathLevel1 . is there any way I can achieve this.

```
 return $analytics->data_ga->get(
          'ga:' . $profileId,
          $start_date,
          $end_date,
          'ga:pageviews,ga:uniquePageviews',

          array('dimensions' => 'ga:pagePathLevel1', 'filters' => $filter ) );


    }
```

Another Note is ,

> I am using it to get analytics report of another of my site, I have
>   added a select box to select the site and retrieving the data , I want
>   to achieve this working for both .

Note:-I am not using "gapi" api, It is only google client api PHP, no idea id It has the facility to create a custom dimension and get server response code for all pages.

If It is not possible, Can any one suggest, if I can filter out all pages having server response code 404 and get all pages which are currently on site.

*If it needs more details to answer me, please ask questions, I will add the new required details to this question.*

Comment: Loop through the results of the function, prepend the base url to ech pagepath and feed the resulting url to the get_headers function ( http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php) - is that the kind of thing you are looking for ? Current http status (or http status at all for that matter) is not stored within GA (by default, you could set a custom dimension on your error pages).

Comment: @EikePierstorff Thank you for your response, Can I set a custom dimension on my plugin and that will work , even if I will install it on any other website in future, with out using the dashboard provided by google analytics ? Any resources where I can get better idea of doing it , if possible ?

Comment: @EikePierstorff I did it,but trying to find better method as it is slowing down my result page. thank you.

Comment: Yes, calling remote pages is a pretty expensive operation. For that other idea, you cannot set the http status from javascript, so you would need to modify your error pages on the server to include the code that sets the custom dimension.

Comment: @EikePierstorff for my site I may do it, but I would like to do something that will work for everyone, We are developers , better is to learn and work hard and get a better way than workaround . I hope I will find some idea on it, and please let me know, if you will get one and also there is a chance, some one post here .

Comment: It's not that I do not agree, but Javascript will not give you the http status code and most error pages are set by the server, so your script will be not able to modify them. If you're just after status code from within your php app you can use ga("set","dimension1", "<?php echo http_response_code(); ?>"); before your pageview call (set up the dimension in your GA property beforehand).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99444/discussion-between-prafulla-kumar-sahu-and-eike-pierstorff).

Comment: @EikePierstorff I have modified my question, can you please  give any suggestion or idea on new status.